# How to access one model within another model in Rails..?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have one data model 'object' with fields->object_id, object_name.
That is: http://localhost:3000/objects/

I have created another model 'front_pages' (not created any migration in this, instead I have created some pages like 'search.html.erb'(by hand) and the associated controllers).
That is: http://localhost:3000/front_pages/

My question is: How to access/search the items stored in the 'object' database within the 'search.html.erb'.

"These two are in the same rails project folder"

-> How to display the search results into an HTML.erb file?

> views/static_pages/show.html.erb

```
<% @npsobject.each do |npsobjects| %>
```

Nps:

Nps type:
  
 Nps name:
  

 |

> Static_page Controller

```
 class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
      @npsobject=Npsobject.find(:all, :conditions => ['nps_name LIKE ?',  "%#{params[ :search]}%"]);
       end
```

> views/static_pages/new.html.erb

```
   <%= form_tag( { :action =>"show"}, { :method => "get"}) do %> # The action path is ok??
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'inputBox' %>
```

"button") %>

Please verify the above codes and guide me through, as Im new to RoR..:)

Comment: and why are urls important? This is a job for a controller so paste controller method responsible for this "search" form you created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your

```
    @npsobject = Npsobject.find
```

into `show` action
and then `each` it into your `views/static_pages/show.html.erb`

```
    <% @npsobject.each do |nps| %>
      <%= nps.nps_name %>
    <% end %>
```